# How to create Runner.xcworkspace in your flutter app?

Tags: ios, testing, flutter, dart, runner

I have a flutter app that I code in Android Studio. I also have XCode.

I would like to test the app on my actual iPhone.

I googled, and many stated to simply open the Runner.xcworkspace on Xcode. However, I do not have the Runner.xcworkspace file in the iOS folder, as they had described.

Once source advised to run "pod install" on terminal or "flutter run", but I have been unsuccessful.

On terminal, my steps are:

```
cd Desktop 
cd MyApp
cd ios
```

--> here, there are two folders: Runner, and Flutter

I have tried "pod install", and "flutter run" in Runner, and "pod install", and "flutter run" in Runner, and both were unsuccessful, stating:

```
[!] No `Podfile' found in the project directory.
zsh: command not found: flutter
```

Please advise on how I can create the Runner.xcworkspace

Thank you very, very much!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your project file is corrupted. A fresh Flutter project doesn't have a `Podfile` by default, so there's no point to run cocoapods.

You can try recreating your app. In your case, `cd` to your project root (MyApp), and run

```
flutter create .
```

Note there's a dot at the end. Then flutter cli will try to fix your problem.

Comment: My app is titled Trivia. 

rachykc@Rachels-MacBook-Air ~ % cd Desktop
rachykc@Rachels-MacBook-Air Desktop % cd Flutter
rachykc@Rachels-MacBook-Air Flutter % cd Trivia
rachykc@Rachels-MacBook-Air Trivia % flutter create .
zsh: command not found: flutter
rachykc@Rachels-MacBook-Air Trivia % 

It states that the command was not found. Please advise! Thanks so much.

Comment: Did you install Flutter at all?

Comment: "folder-name" is not a valid Dart package name